# jQuery Mobile :: Scroll does not stop on Samsung Galaxy S3 (Android 4.0.4)

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am learning jQuery mobile and I did small app to see list of all countries and its brief info. I have developed a scrolling list with ul and li. I tested my app on All browsers and it works fine but when I tested it on Samsung Galaxy S3 and Google Nexus, I got strange observations.

Here are my observations -

**On Samsung Galaxy (Android 4.0.4) -**

a) Whenever I scroll the list, scrolling does not stop even if there are no records. It shows white background with no records in it.

b) Whenever I try to click on the list, list flickers upside or downside and opens wrong list item instead of desired list item.

c) Mobile's back button does not exit and takes back to my mobiles app gallery. It keeps moving through the history of pages.

**On Google Nexus (Android 4.3) -**

1) Scrolling works perfectly fine and it stops at the end of the records.

2) List does not flicker like upside / downside. Opens desired item.

3) Like Samsung galaxy S3, it keeps moving me through all the history pages instead of existing me out of app.

Since its working on Google nexus, it doesn't look like code problem but not sure.

Can someone please help to resolve the problems which I have been facing on Samsung Galaxy S3 ?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem. It was causing due to height specified for page. It was 99%. I removed that setting and it started working. Wooo hoo !!